# Position of vertical axis title in Google Charts

Tags: charts

This is probably a simple problem. I am trying to find out how to move a vertical axis title closer to the axis in Google charts. Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes:

Label positioning and style - You can customize label positioning and style using the hAxis/vAxis.textPosition and hAxis/vAxis.textStyle options.

**EDIT:**
Tested using this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YolandaMDavis/Qquse/)

replace `vAxis: {title: 'Year',` with `vAxis: {title: '\nYear',` would "nudge" your Axis title closer

Comment: Thanks but that is not exactly what I am trying to do. I have a vAxis title that looks fine. The only change I want to make is to nudge it closer to the values on the axis.

Comment: If you want to nudge it closer try adding \n in the title field for example vAxis: {title: '\n Your Axis Here'},

Comment: so, that effectively adds a line space? Thanks!

Comment: No problem! If my answer solved your question i'd greatly appreciate it if you accept it as a solution :)

Comment: probably really dumb but i don't see the check box to accept the solution. It worked fine :-)